# program that loads integers until a zero is loaded and then prints the maximum among them and which one was it

Tags: python

> I Have problem when i enter a sequence of [-2,-2,-5,6,0] it prints -2 not 6 problem on break any other solution for that ?

```
 z = []
    a = 0
    max = 0
    while True:
        b = int(input("Enter a Number ").strip())
        z.append(b)
        if b == 0:
            break
    while a < len(z) :
        if z[a] > z[a+1]:
           max = z[a]
           break
        a += 1
    print(f"the max number is {max} his appearence  is :{z.count(max)}")
```

Comment: if i dont use break a error will pop off it says IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: this is because of the last iteration of the second while loop where `a=len(z)-1`. in the `if` you look for `z[a+1]` which is out of bounds. update your code so you don't need this `break`

Comment: should it print the 0 too if it was the highest number?

Comment: No it has to remove it from the list

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a keyword such as 'max' as a variable. Also, as mentioned in comments, check your while loop logic. Here's a solution for your problem if you are okay with using functions/methods.

```
z = []
while True:
    b = int(input("Enter a Number ").strip())
    z.append(b)
    if b == 0:
        break
max_value = max(z)
index_of_max = z.index(max(z))
print(f"the max number is {max_value} his appearence  is :{index_of_max}")
```

Comment: `index_of_max = z.index(max_value)` would be better

Comment: i did this z = []
while True:
    b = int(input("Enter a Number ").strip())
    z.append(b)
    if b == 0:
        break
z.remove(0)
max_value = max(z)
print(f"the max number is {max_value} his appearence  is :{z.count(max_value)}")